# What comes first the cte or the variable

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to write a query that will declare two variables ("start" and "end" number) then will insert into an cte via a loop, every value between the start and end below is what I have so far, am I doing something silly?

EDIT: I am trying to insert 1 - 100 into the cte recording each insert via the print statement.
What I am trying to gain from this is experience with regards to using variables and cte's in the same ad-hoc script.

```
    WITH growing AS 
                (
                    SELECT 1 variable
                    FROM dual
                )
DECLARE 
            Start_Point number  := 1;
            End_Point   number  := 100;
BEGIN
        LOOP
                INSERT INTO growing VALUES (Start_Point);
                Start_Point := (Start_Point + 1);
                dbms_output.put.line(Start_Point);
                IF (SELECT COUNT(variable) FROM Growing WHERE variable = End_Point) > 0  EXIT;
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'insert into a CTE'? You're mixinf SQl and PL/SQL in an odd way... can you edit the question explain what you are actually trying to achieve, including what output/result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not related at all.

A CTE is attached to a `SELECT` statement.  It is a way of naming a subquery *within* the `SELECT`.  The rest of your code is scripting code, which in Oracle is called PL/SQL.  Scripting code is different from a `SELECT` statement.

You cannot insert into a CTE.  It is really just a short-hand for a subquery.  I speculate that you want a temporary table or some sort of set.  If you need help solving a problem, I would suggest asking *another* question, providing an explanation of what you want to do, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: I am unable to create a temp table as in my current environment unable to create/drop tables also don't have the ability to create an database to experiment, as I have been told that temp tables have to be dropped other wise they persist within the schema? I thought an CTE might have been a good work-around. Although I may be completely miss-understanding how temp tables work within oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert into a CTE, and you can't hang a PL/SQL block off a CTE - only a query. (Though you can embed PL/SQL *into* a CTE from 12c).

If you want to generate the values in a range you could use a hierarchical query:

```
with growing (variable) as (
  select <start_point> + level - 1
  from dual
  connect by level <= <end_point>
)
```

where `<start_point>` and `<end_point>` are placeholders you need to replace with literal values, or (depending on how you will use this) substituion or bind variable. So with your range as fixed literals:

```
with growing (variable) as (
  select 1 + level - 1
  from dual
  connect by level <= 100
)
select * from growing;

  VARIABLE
----------
         1
         2
         3
...
        99
       100
```

or use a recursive CTE:

```
with growing (variable) as (
  select <start_point> from dual
  union all
  select variable + 1
  from growing
  where variable < <end_point>
)
```

so:

```
with growing (variable) as (
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select variable + 1
  from growing
  where variable < 100
)
select * from growing;

  VARIABLE
----------
         1
         2
         3
...
        99
       100
```

If you're trying to combine this with PL/SQL variables then you could use the CTE in a cursor loop, referring to the local PL/SQL variables within the CTE:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  start_point number := 1;
  end_point   number := 100;
begin
  for r in (
    with growing (variable) as (
      select 1 from dual
      union all
      select variable + start_point
      from growing
      where variable < end_point
    )
    select * from growing
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.variable);
  end loop;
end;
/

1
2
3
...
98
99

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

but you'd really need to be using the CTE as part of a bigger query, whether that's in plain SQL or as part of a PL/SQL block.

To just print the values in PL/SQL you don't need a CTE, just a simple loop:

```
declare
  start_point number := 1;
  end_point   number := 100;
begin
  for i in start_point..end_point loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

but again you'd expect to be doing something more useful with the generated numbers, of course. If you had a temporary table already created at schema level then you could insert into that (via PL/SQL or plain SQL). (Those are supposed to persist; the table is permenant, at least for global temporary tables; the *data* is temporary. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-23B23DCF-7482-4585-9C63-AC073C5DE224)). Or you could populate a table collection, e.g.

```
declare
  type t_tab is table of number;
  tab t_tab := t_tab();
  start_point number := 1;
  end_point   number := 100;
begin
  for i in start_point..end_point loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
    tab.extend();
    tab(tab.count) := i;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

It really depends what you need to do with the generated numbers and whatever you store them in (if anything).